# Php different images in every page

Tags: php

I am designing my own site. First I created a template with `header.php` and `footer.php` I put them in the `includes` folder. So, everytime I am going to make a new page like "about page" all I have to do is to call them using the code below:

```
<body>
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code in my header.php

```
<div id="headwrapper">
    <header>
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/adlogo.png"/></div>
    <div id="homefeature">622x82</div>
    <div id="nav"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.htm">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
</div><!--end of headwrapper-->
```

But my `index.php` and my about page have the same header image. Is there a way or code that can accomplish the work for different header images for every page? Example on index.php I want to have image1 and to my about page I want to have image2. That's all thank you by the way I am not using a wordpress my site is not a wordpress.

Comment: Why not simply edit `about.php` and add a new header image like you've done in `header.php`?

Comment: yeah first I thought of that way but I want to experiment and learn of more possibilities.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution.

In header.php you call function $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for get page name and then selected image for that page. You could modify like this

```
<?php
    $imageName = ""; 
    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "index.php")
    {
        $imageName = "images/1.png";
    }
    elseif($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "aboutus.php")
    {
        $imageName = "images/2.png";
    }
?>    
<div id="headwrapper">
    <header>
    <div id="logo"><img src="'".<?=$imageName?>."'"/></div>
    <div id="homefeature">622x82</div>
    <div id="nav"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.htm">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
</div><!--end of headwrapper-->
```

Comment: by the way what if i have 5 pages do i have to repeat the elseif statement?

Comment: Maybe you can naming you image like page name. When you call $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], you should replace ".php" to ".png".
<?php $imageName = str_replace($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php",".png");?>

Comment: hello again the image wont show up i just see a little square inside my homefeature div do i need to make my image as png? maybe the problem was my image is in jpg format.

Comment: Could you show me more code detail? Maybe is has some little mistake. thank

Comment: I just copied your example then I put the <img src="'".<?=$imageName?>."'"/> in my homefeature div i replace the 622x82.

Comment: Do you run website on localhost/testwebsite or on real hosting? If run on localhost/testwebsite when you call $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] it will return name of your folder of website and page that open e.g. "testwebsite/aboutus.php" so you need to replace "testwebsite" to "". Anyway If use run hosting that has domain name e.g. www.testwebsite.com when you open page aboutus.php it like you access www.testwebsite.com/aboutus.php at this situation you call $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] it will return only aboutus.php.
I answer by prediction situation if it is not correct please tell me.

Comment: hello I run my site locally. Thank you I will try this one I'll let you know if i still encountering a problem thank you so much!

Comment: Hi is this correct if($_Server['PHP_SELF'] == "mysite/aboutus.php")? mysite is the folder where all my pages are in. I tried to do that still the same.

Comment: Yes it is correct. :) The result is ok as you want it or not.

Comment: You should try to echo $_Server['PHP_SELF']; and see what result then modify some code for it. Maybe if another problem you can contact me with my email because it has a lot of comment in this answer. Thank.

Comment: See in my account info.

Answer (score 0):

Given your structure, I think you can set your header file like this:

```
<body>
    <?php $header_image = "about_us_header.jpg"; ?>
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
```

and reference the variable in your header:

```
<div id="headwrapper">
<header style="background: url(<?php echo $header_image; ?>);">
```

---

*But wait I thought of a better way*

you can do it in css like this:

```
<body class="aboutus">
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
```

and in your css stylesheet:

```
body.aboutus header { 
    background: url(whatever.jpg);
}
```

Comment: hi willoller thanks I will try your suggestion. Thank you so much!